# How to deal with high CPU usage on a 1.4GHz AMD E1-1200 processor with a fresh Windows 10 Home install

Tags: windows-10, high-cpu-usage

I have installed a fresh Windows 10 Home version on my HP 2000 laptop that has a 1.4GHz AMD E1-1200 processor. Even after all the Windows updates are completed and no software is opened up, the CPU usage is always high and the system is very slow in general. The OS is running off an SSD and 8GB RAM. Is there any way to deal with this issue?

Thanks.

Edit :

After seeing some comments, I wanted to clarify something. I have installed Windows 10 in laptops running Core 2 Duo processors and 4GB RAM and noticed they perform well. The problem seems to be only with this processor so, my question was actually to find out if I can do something to run Windows 10 smoothly on this. Many times, the high CPU usage is due to Antimalware process running in background but I don't know if its safe or even possible to permanently disable it. I will try to install some Linux Distro as advised by some users to see if that helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the processor requirements for every version of Windows 10.  Your processor does not appear to be supported. The performance issues you are experiencing are likely connected to this fact.  Did this machine come with Windows 10 already installed?

Comment: What have you tried?, other versions of windows / flavors of linux? It is a 10 years old CPU. Windows 10 is going to run ofc but really slow.

Comment: At the very least you would have to give us some idea of what you see using CPU in Task Manager. Even after Windows updates there are sometimes optimisation steps that need to happen. There are some in .NET at the very least.

Comment: `1.4GHz dualcore` low performance is totally expected.

Comment: On old systems that won't support Windows, I find Linux uses far fewer resources and CPU time. Test some distro of Linux, to see if it works better in that situation.

Comment: All - I agree with most of your comments hence I provided some clarification to my question. I will install some Linux Distro and see if that makes this processor worth using for general purpose computing.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to disable Windows Defender on Windows 10.  The only supported way is to replace it with another AV, this will resulting the ability of enabling the background scanning for additional protection, but Windows Defender will still exist and take some degree of resources.  At the end of the day the processor is significantly close to the absolutely minium requirements.  Past experiences depending, on what version of Windows 10 you installed, are very difficult to compare to.